# Grant access to other users through a service account so that they can access a bucket through UI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops

I have a bucket in another account. I want to attach a service account to the bucket and then attach other users to this service account so that they can access the bucket. Being a DevOps Engineer, I can access the bucket through CLI either by authenticating the JSON key file or creating a short-lived access token. But, what about the people who only rely on GUI and cannot use the CLI. Is there some way, they can access the bucket through a UI while just being attached to the service account?

I tried Cyberduck for this but it works only if the users are directly attached to the bucket.

Comment: Sounds like you should create a group and grant access to the bucket for that group: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/groups-in-cloud-console

Comment: I will try alternatives later. What i want to know is whether i can access the bucket being attached to a service account, through a UI?